# JSONException while post the data to server in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to sending the data to server using HttpPost in my Android application.But getting org.json.JSONException: No value for ResponseItem while getting the response. But when try to hit this request on server the status will be true . Can someone help me how to solve this issue.

Here is my HttpPost method code

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                StringEntity stringEntity = null;
                HttpResponse httpresponse;
                try {

                    jsonobj.put("ActionDate", strCurrentDateTime);
                    jsonobj.put("ActivityId", strActivityId);
                    jsonobj.put("userId", str_UserId);
                    jsonobj.put("objectId", strVessId);
                    jsonobj.put("NAME", strTitle);
                    jsonobj.put("REMARK", replaceDescChar);
                    jsonobj.put("STATUS", "PENDING");
                    jsonobj.put("TYPE", strType);
                    jsonobj.put("starflag", "0");
                    jsonobj.put("HashTag", editedHashTag);
                    jsonobj.put("Authentication_Token", str_Authentication_Token);

                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    je.printStackTrace();
                }
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(namespace + "/Upd_Post_Activity");


                try
                {
                     stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
                     Log.e("stringEntity "," = "+stringEntity);
                    Log.e(" jsonobj.toString() "," = "+jsonobj.toString());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ue) {
                    ue.printStackTrace();
                }
                stringEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                stringEntity.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");

                try {

                    post.setEntity(stringEntity);
                    httpresponse = httpclient.execute(post);

                    Log.d(" @@@@ Http Post :", " Response " + httpresponse.toString());
                    InputStream inputStream = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    if (inputStream != null)
                        strEditableResult = Constant.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    else
                        strEditableResult = "Did not work!";
                    Log.e("Editable Post", " = " + strEditableResult);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is my Error log information

```
Editable Post﹕ = {"Upd_Post_ActivityResult":{"ResponseItem":"120160121172258001","Status":"false"}}
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk E/jsonResult﹕ = {"Upd_Post_ActivityResult":{"ResponseItem":"120160121172258001","Status":"false"}}
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for ResponseItem
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.Edit_Post$9.doInBackground(Edit_Post.java:1149)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.Edit_Post$9.doInBackground(Edit_Post.java:908)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-22 12:33:30.464  24750-25019/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: what is at line number 1149 in `Edit_Post.java`

Comment: but why to false  my jsonResult﹕ = {"Upd_Post_ActivityResult":{"ResponseItem":"120160121170602039","Status":"false"}}String strresponce = jsonObj.getString("ResponseItem");
                        Log.e("strresponce ", " = " + strresponce);

Comment: Why the status is false, that you have to check on server side code. Why JsonException because you are not reading response properly. What is the value of jsonObj? Is it  jsonObj = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("Upd_Post_ActivityResult")?

Comment: It seems data type issue for ResponseItem value as server side.

Comment: It should be BigInteger guess.

Comment: Sorry late reply , because i have no net connection . Yes i have to have to check on server side code , there is no any problem .